# astype is not working for conversion from object to int in python

Tags: python, casting

I am using astype function to convert the datatype of a variable imdbrating from object to int. please help

command used : `imdb['imdbRating']=imdb['imdbRating'].astype(int)`

error faced:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '8.1'

Comment: Well, probably because it's a float?

Answer (score 2):

You need convert values to `float`s:

```
imdb['imdbRating']=imdb['imdbRating'].astype(float)
```

and if necesseary then convert it to `integer`s:

```
imdb['imdbRating']=imdb['imdbRating'].astype(float).astype(int)
```